# Windows 10 update is somehow blocking HTTP connects between web browser and a localhost app

Tags: ajax, windows-10

We provide a web application SAS for invoicing that allows printing to a thermal printer. It prints via a local application that runs on background with a web server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080. When the web app wants to print it communicates via a AJAX POST to http://localhost:8080 and then the local app just routes it to the USB printer.
Everything was working fine, but suddenly it looks like that a windows update this week somehow is blocking the AJAX connection from the browser to the local running app.

- Windows 7 users are still working flawlessly (and a few Windows XP users around).
- The users are running the latest Chrome 76.0.3809.100 and Firefox 68.0.2 and both fail. The exact same browsers where tested with Linux and Windows 7 and everything works.
- Of course we disabled the AV and firewall to test but no avail.
- We get and error on the console with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when connecting to "http://localhost:8080".

There is some kind of policy or setting that we can be missing? We are mostly a Linux shop and this has strike us by surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to clarify if the machine is plugged to the printer. Or is it all network printer. I know its not the printer.
Looks like windows changed something in dns or preventing a null ip address. Either way, regedit is where you will most likely find your answer. Its like the .conf file of linux. Just a matter of what entry needs adjusted. 
Rambling, will wait your response